Conjecture for Torricelli's parallelogram paradox
Evangelista Torricelli demonstrated a geometrical paradox concerning his view on the homogeneous/heterogeneous debate of the 1600s
(see p.125 Jullien, Vincent, Jullien, Vincent (ed.), Seventeenth-century indivisibles revisited. Cham: Springer (ISBN 978-3-319-00130-2/hbk; 978-3-319-00131-9/ebook). Science Networks. Historical Studies 49, 451-457 (2015). ZBL1327.01008.).
I have a conjecture on how to rigorously resolve his paradox but I am seeking a method and feedback on writing the shortest proof possible (without using Leibniz's notation):
Torricelli Parallelogram Paradox
Instead of a line having points on it, assume that a line is made of points and that the number of points in a line determine the length.  Two lines that are of the same length have the same number of points.  A shorter line has less points and a longer line has more points.
Now take a parallelogram with the four corner points labeled A,B,C, and D.  Draw a line BD down the diagonal of it as shown in the figure.  Let us make a point E on the diagonal line BD.  Now draw perpendicular lines from E to a point F on AD, and a second line to a point G on CD.  Move these two lines point by point simultaneously so that E moves toward D until they meet, keeping the lines EF and EG always parallel to AB and BC respectively.  When we move the lines EF and EG, we are moving their ends simultaneously from point to point on AD, CD and BD.
Since line AD is shorter than the line CD, the number of points that the line AD contains is less than the number of points that line CD contains.  However, this creates a paradox. Since we moved the lines point by point and with both points F and G ending up together at point D then this shows that lines AD and CD must also have the same number of points.
Conjecture: Assume a line is composed of infinitesimal segments SEG and that the sum of the magnitude of these infinitesimal segments determines the length of the line.  The length of line AD would be
$$
\sum|SEG_{AD}|\equiv \textbf{length}_{AD}.
$$
If the infinitesimal segments are of equal magnitude within the line, then the line is intrinsically flat.
$$
|SEG^n_{AD}|-|SEG^{n-1}_{AD}|=0
$$
If the infinitesimal segments are of differing magnitude, then the line is intrinsically curved.
$$
|SEG^n_{AD}|-|SEG^{n-1}_{AD}|\neq 0
$$
If two separate lines are intrinsically flat respective to each other (segments are of same magnitude) then the line with the greater number of segments will be the longer line.  Let me call the number of segments the relative cardinality (RC).  Assume RC is infinite but can have different values (transfinite).
$$
RC_{AD}*|SEG_{AD}|\equiv \textbf{length}_{AD}.
$$
Thus the length of a line can change via a scale factor $f$ from two different ways, either by scaling the magnitude of the segments scaled magnitudes
$$
f*AD=RC_{AD}*(f*|SEG_{AD}|)
$$
or by scaling the relative cardinality scaled cardinality
$$
f*AD=(f*RC_{AD})*|SEG_{AD}|.
$$
I conjecture that Torricelli's paradox can be resolved by holding the RC equal between the two lines with the segments of BD larger than in AD instead of BD having larger RC than AD.
$$
\frac{RC_{AD}*|SEG_{AD}|}{RC_{BD}*|SEG_{BD}|}
$$
Some of the notation to represent cardinality (i.e. using natural numbers) would not apply here so trying to think this through.  As an example, the Archimedean axiom expression here treats $f$ as a natural number and a scaling factor for the $\epsilon$.  If $\epsilon$ is an infinitesimal, this expression is said not to apply since any number times an infinitesimal obviously is not greater than 1 (which I believe this proof would falsify).
$$
(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists f \in \mathbb{N}) [f\epsilon>1]
$$
Bair, Jacques; Błaszczyk, Piotr; Ely, Robert; Henry, Valérie; Kanovei, Vladimir; Katz, Karin U.; Katz, Mikhail G.; Kutateladze, Semen S.; McGaffey, Thomas; Schaps, David M.; Sherry, David; Shnider, Steven, Is mathematical history written by the victors?, Notices Am. Math. Soc. 60, No. 7, 886-904 (2013). ZBL1334.01010.
How would you write relative cardinality RC using modern notation?
